# Gold badges on grey background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

I looked a lot at badge icons to make up my mind about the latest changes and I noticed something about the colors that is independent of the shapes (hence a new post):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Gold badges are kind of hard to see clearly (for me) on grey (tag badge) or light blue (author box) -- that is, lower contrast -- backgrounds. On white (editor box) and black (top bar) they look amazing!

I guess the badge colors are fixed network-wide, but maybe something can be done about relevant backgrounds?

Comment: Wow, with Redshift running at 2700K it's even worse. But that's a localized issue, so I'll not include it in the "official" critique.

Comment: most of colors you mentioned is consistent network-wise. i can update it a little for author box and will do that.

Comment: @Paweł I see. Thanks for using the wiggle room you have, anyway!